# MFC: How to redraw window before it appears in new position on dragging

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I move child window over parent window and I need to implement effect of transparency of child window in relation to parent window. That means the child window should contain the corresponding part of content of the parent window.
In debugging I realized that  child window's method `OnPaint()` is called after this window appears in the new position with old content. It produces annoying effect of content's trembling.
So, the question is how to force child window to process `WM_PAINT` message before it appears in the new position.

I do `Invalidate()` before child window going to be repositioned.

```
void CTextBoxDlg::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{  
    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);  
    Invalidate();
}
```

This is my `OnPaint`

```
void CTextBoxDlg::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
  CDC* pParentDC = m_pParentWnd->GetDC();
  CRect rect;
  GetWindowRect(&rect);
  dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), pParentDC, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);
  dsc.Draw(dc);
  CDialog::OnPaint();
}
```

Comment: `OnPain` sounds like a horrific event handler.

Comment: But check out `RedrawWindow` (IIRC).

Comment: RedrawWindow seems to do the same thing Invalidate() does. At least I tried RedrawWindow(0, 0, RDW_INTERNALPAINT); in OnWindowPosChanging and it didn't help.

Comment: This won't work, you can't blit the contents of an arbitrary window DC. You need to request that the other window draw itself into your DC using something like the `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message. The `RedrawWindow` function has *lots* of flags. `RDW_INTERNALPAINT` is *not* one that you want to use. You want the combination of flags that causes an *immediate* repaint, producing the same effect as `InvalidateRect`+`UpdateWindow`. Anyway, if you just want transparency, consider using layered windows.

Comment: Look at handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxb29894(v=vs.120).aspx.  This is called just before a window is moved (and/or resized).  Here you can change the source and desitination rectangles used for that automatic blit when a window is moved.  You can even disable the automatic blit by specifying a zero-sized source and dest rect here.  And if you then do your awful parent window DC blit in this handler, instead of in `OnPaint`, you can get perfect flicker-free window  animation, but this is bad and I can't recomment it in a public forum.